# AS3 - geometry - perspective projection of a point on a 2D plane

Tags: actionscript-3, math, 3d, geometry

I'm currently struggling on a problem that seems far beyond my maths capacities (been a long time since I've made some proper maths...) and I would appreciate some help on that.

Here's my setting :
I got some simple shapes (rectangles), and I "project" their bottom points on a line, coming from an Origin point.
Up to this point everything is fine.
But now I'd like to draw the original shape distorted as if it was projected with some perspective on a plane.

Please consider that I have nothing related to any rotation, isometric or any 3D or fake 2D perspective in my code, I'm only trying to draw some shapes using the graphics library to only have a *feeling* of something real.

Here's a quick drawing of what I'm trying to do :

[image]

**What I know :**

- Origin point coordinates
- the rect position & sizes
- the red line position
- the A & B points coordinates

**What I want to determine is the coordinates of the C & D points**, thing that could be easy if I wasn't struggling to find the "Origin bis" coordinates.

What I'm trying to do is to fake the projection of my rectangle on something that can be considered as a "floor" (related to the plane where my original rectangle is that can be seen as a wall).

*Maybe I'm over-complicating the problem or maybe I fail to see any other easier way to do it, but I'm really not good anymore in any geometry or maths thing... :-(*

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: I don't understand, are you looking only at the projection of the bottom of the rectangle? if so, when looking from a different angle you will see only a line and not the whole rectangle. If you want the whole rectangle you have to project all of it on the red line.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make what I want clear enough :-s  What I'm really trying to have is a projection of my rectangle on a plane (that  supposedly form a 90° angle with the plane of my original rectangle) with the bottom of the projection sitting on the red line. My drawing was supposed to explain it well: the A & B points are projections of the bottom points of my rectangle, and the C & D are the projection of the top ones, but with a different perspective. Think of the shadow of a vertical monolith floating in mid air projected onto the floor by a light coming from somewhere in its back...

Comment: shouldnt c and d also be projected on the red line, and then just viewed from a different perspective? In your analogy, the "shadow" of the whole object will be on one surface...

Comment: Yeah but as I stated in my original question, I have no real plans, no 3D space... All I'm doing is some drawing onto a bitmapData to fake the perspective...

Comment: So, is Origin bis something that has to be generated, or is it a set variable somewhere? This would be easier we had anything like one of the origin Bi coordinates or one of the green lines. The green lines would give us the ability to create fake right triangles. Something like the origin Bis is used like the cameras in a 3D scene

Comment: No the fact is that I don't know at all neither C, D nor Origin bis. This last point doesn't exist for the moment, its the only thing that I could think of to help me find C & D (with simple points projections). I anybody has a different way of viewing the problem, I'm open to everything ! :-)

Comment: It is very difficult to find a suitable mathematical interpretation of “feeling of something real”. Without context, there is little to distinguish solutions. Perhaps the best way would be to actually think in 3D, and do computations in 3D. In the end, you will come up with formulas for your coordinates, and those you can use to draw things using 2D routines. Might be that this approach makes the computation a bit harder, but it also should make the question more tangible and therefore easier to answer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was afraid of... I was hoping for some magical thing to help me fake some 3D perspective without 3D... I'm gonna think about going 3D for the computations at least, thanks !

Comment: I think this problem is an exact fit for the limited 3D capabilities that Adobe put in Flash. Is there a specific reason you can't use this?
Because your problem would be solved in 1 minute: copy the rectangle, and  rotate it around its X-axis. You can set your perspective point and even move it around. You can have multiple rectangles and shadows and they will all "feel" exactly real.

Comment: In other words: draw a rectangle using the graphics engine, and then: myRectangle.rotationX = 45;

Answer (score 0):

hmm i don't know if I undestood it correctly but I think you have too few input parameters:

you said the following information is given:

- Origin point coordinates
- the rect position & sizes
- the red line position
- the A & B points coordinates

I don't think it is possible to get your projected rectangle with this information alone.
Additionally, I think your green lines and the 'origin Bis' aren't helpful as well.

Perhaps, try this:
Supose, a blue line going through the points C & D is given as well.
Then you could find your projected rectangle by projecting the top of the rectangle onto that blue line.

So in summary:
You define an origin + two parallel lines, a red and a blue one.
Then you can project the top of the rect onto the blue line and the bottom of the rect onto the red line, yielding the points A,B,C,D

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but yeah I didn't mentionned that blue line you're talking about in my post because I forgot :-) The fact is : if I have that blue line, how can I project the top of the rect onto it ? I cannot simply project them from the same Origin point, it would feel like some light hiting a floor, I need to know/find an horizontal offset between the top projections and the bottom projections for my projected rectangle to really feel projected with the right angle from the original shape (thus the Origin bis point that was intended to give me that angle difference...)

Comment: hmm I don't know anything about how projections should 'feel', but mostly two types of projections are used. Orthogonal or Perspective. In Perspective projection you have one origin point and project by drawing lines from origin through your points of the rectangle. That is the version I suggested. In Orthogonal Projection you only presribe one direction vector and project the points in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, this code will show what you wanted to see.

First of all, I've ignored your initial setup of objects and information, and focused on the example situation itself; fake-projecting shadow for a "monolith" (any object is possible with the example below, even textured)
My reason was that it's really quite easy with the `Matrix` class of ActionScript, a handy tool worth learning.

Solution:
You can use the built-in `Matrix` class to do skew transform on `DisplayObject`s.
Try this example:

(The "useful" part lies in the _EF EnterFrame handler ;) )

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

const PIP180:Number = Math.PI / 180;
const MAX_SHADOW_HEIGHT_MULTIPLIER:Number = 0.25; // you can also calculate this from an angle, like ... = Math.sin(angle * PIP180);
const ANIM_DEG_PER_FRAME:Number = 1.0 * PIP180; // the shadow creeps at a +1 degree per frame rate

var tx:BitmapData = new MonolithTexture(); // define this BitmapData in the library
var skew:Number = -10 * PIP180; // initial 

var mono:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mono.graphics.beginBitmapFill(tx);
// drawn that way the registration point is 0,0, so it's standing on the ground
mono.graphics.drawRect(0, -tx.height, tx.width, tx.height);
mono.graphics.endFill();

// align monolith to the "ground"
mono.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
mono.y = stage.stageHeight - 100;
// make it be 100x300 pixel
mono.width = 100;
mono.height = 300;

var shad:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
// colored:
shad.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
// or textured:
//shad.graphics.beginBitmapFill(tx);
shad.graphics.drawRect(0, -tx.height, tx.width, tx.height);
shad.graphics.endFill();

addChild(shad); // shadow first
addChild(mono); // then the caster object

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _EF);

function _EF(e:Event):void {
    // animate skew on the positive half circle
    skew = (skew + ANIM_DEG_PER_FRAME) % Math.PI;

    // Matrix takes 6 parameters: a, b, c, d, x, y
    // for this shadow trick, use them as follows:
    // a = width scaling (as mono and shad are drawn in the same way, copy mono.scaleX for a perfect fit
    // b = 0, because we don't want to project the vertical axis of transformation to the horizontal
    // c = horizontal skew
    // d = height scaling * skew * making it a bit flat using the constant
    // x = mono.x, ...
    // y = mono.y since originally mono and shad look alike, only the Matrix makes shad render differently
    var mtx:Matrix = new Matrix(mono.scaleX, 0, Math.cos(skew), mono.scaleY * Math.sin(skew) * MAX_SHADOW_HEIGHT_MULTIPLIER, mono.x, mono.y);
    shad.transform.matrix = mtx;
}
```

Now all you got to know to utilize this in your case, is the following N factors:
Q1: from what angle you want to project the shadow?
A1: horizontal factor is the `skew` variable itself, while vertical angle is stored as constant here, called `MAX_SHADOW_HEIGHT_MULTIPLIER`

Q2: do you want to project shadow only "upwards", or freely?
A2: if "upwards" is fine, keep `skew` in the positive range, otherwise let it take negative values as well for a "downward" shadow

P.S.: if you render the internals of the objects that they don't snap to 0 y as a base point, you can make them seem float/sink, or offset both objects vertically with a predefined value, with the opposite sign.

Answer (score 0):

You face 1 very simple problem, as you said:

'What I want to determine is the coordinates of the C & D points, thing that could be easy if I wasn't struggling to find the "Origin bis" coordinates.'

But these co-ordinates relate to each other, so without one (or another value such as an angle) you cannot have the other. If you are to try this in 3D you are simply allowing the 3D engine to define 'Origin bis' and do your calculating for C and D itself.

So regardless you will need an 'Original bis', another value relating to the redline or your Rect for which to calculate the placement of C and D.

I remember making stuff like this and sometimes it's better to just stick with simple, you either make an 'Original bis' defines by yourself (it can be either stationary or move with the player/background) and get C and D the way you got A and B only that you use a lower line than the red line, or as I would of done, once you have A and B, simple skew/rotate your projection from those points down a bit further, and you get something the same as an 'Original bis' that follows the player. This works fine at simulating 'feeling of something real' but sadly as has been said, it looking real depends on what you are portraying. We do not know what the areas above or below the red line are (sky/ground, ground/water) and whether 'Origin' and 'Origin bis' is your light source, vanishing point, etc.